# Find biggest subset that sums to zero in excel or access(vba,sql or anything)

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, sum, subset

I have a column of numbers in excel, with positives and negatives. It is an accounting book. I need to eliminate cells that sums to zero. It means I want to remove the subset, so the rest of element can not form any subset to sum to zero. I think this problem is to find the largest subset sum. By remove/eliminate, I mean to mark them in excel.

For example: 
a set {1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,5,-5,6,7,8,9},

I need a function that find subset {1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,5,-5} and mark each element.

Comment: How exactly do you want them marked?

Comment: if this is accounting and you are matching positives to corresponding negatives, and they won't be unique numbers, (there will likely be duplicates), so {1,-1,1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,4,5,-5} will all match but not sum to zero until you reconcile them. Lance asks correctly how you want them marked. Conditionally format?

Answer (score 1):

This suggestion may be a little heavy-handed, but it should be able to handle a broad class of problems -- like when one credit may be zeroed out by more than one debit (or vice versa) -- if that's what you want.  Like you asked for, it will literally find the largest subset that sums to zero:

1. Enter your numbers in column A, say in the range A1:A14.
2. In column B, beside your numbers, enter `0` in each of the cells B1:B14.  Eventually, these cells will be set to 1 if the corresponding number in column A is selected, or 0 if it isn't.
3. In cell C1, enter the formula `=A1*B1`. Copy the formula down to cells C2:C14.
4. At the bottom of column B, in cell B15, enter the formula `=SUM(B1:B14)`.  This formula calculates the count of your numbers that are selected.
5. At the bottom of column C, in cell C15, enter the formula `=SUM(C1:C14)`.  This formula calculates the sum of your numbers that are selected.
6. Activate the Solver Add-In and use it for the steps that follow.
7. Set the objective to maximize the value of cell $B$15 -- in other words, to maximize the count of your numbers that are selected (that is, to find the largest subset).
8. Set the following three constraints to require the values in cells B1:B14 (that indicate whether or not each of your numbers is selected) to be 0 or 1:  a) `$B$1:$B$14 >= 0`, b) `$B$1:$B$14 <= 1`, and, c) `$B$1:$B$14 = integer`.
9. Set the following constraint to require the selected numbers to add up to 0: `$C$15 = 0`.
10. Use the Solver Add-In to solve the problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your methods, Brian. It just works as I asked. Do you know how I can add a threshold. I mean to accept any sum that results less than abosulte value of K. For example, to find the largest subset sums to between -100 to 100. But I still want the sum as close to zero as possible. I think this is more complicated, maybe I need to use VBA.

Comment: One way might be something like this: a) try first with the steps described in my original post , b) if you get a solution, use it, c) otherwise, replace the `$C$15 = 0` equality constraint (from Step 9) with two inequality constraints, say `$C$15 <= 10` and `$C$15 >= -10` to require the sum to be between -10 and 10, and try again, d) if you get a solution, use it, e) otherwise, progressively relax these constraints (say, to replace -10 and 10 with -20 and 20, then with -30 and 30, and so on) and keep trying until you get a solution.

Comment: P.S. If your intent is to always "match" your credits with a single debit of the same magnitude (and vice versa), the method I proposed is probably not the way to go (since it allows one credit to be matched by many debits of different magnitude, and vice versa).  If you clarify your requirement on this point, I (or someone case) can maybe suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to better define your problem because as it is currently stated there is no clear answer.

Here's why. Take this set of numbers:

```
{ -9, -5, -1, 6, 7, 10 }
```

There are 64 possible subsets - including the empty set - and of these three have zero sums:

```
{ -9, -1, 10 }, { -5, -1, 6 } & { }
```

There are two possible "biggest" zero-sum subsets.

If you remove either of these you end up with either of:

```
{ -5, 6, 7 } or { -9, 7, 10 }
```

Neither of these sum to zero, but there's no rule to determine which subset to pick.

You could decide to remove the "merged" set of zero sum subsets. This would leave you with:

```
{ 7 }
```

But does that make sense in your accounting package?

Equally you could just decide to eliminate only pairs of matching positive & negative numbers, but many transactions would involve triples (i.e. sale = cost + tax).

I'm not sure your question can be answered unless you describe your requirements more clearly.